# How to split a "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE as SELECT" into 2 statements to avoid deadlock

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.
I'm not a SQL programmer, but I still have to maintain some scripts. (And it's the Production database, so I'm leery of trying it live first.) Here's a short version of the script:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_status2
ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AS
SELECT t.`Id`, AVG(se.`value`) as `AVG`
FROM tmp_status t, stuff ss, stuff_history se
WHERE 
   etc...
GROUP BY t.`Id`
ORDER BY t.`Id`;
```

I need to split it into 2 because we're deadlocking on the se table. (That is, another process is attempting to update the se table while this script is doing the long-ish CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE.)

```
t.`Id` is defined as  int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
se.`value` is defined as int(10) unsigned
```

Is this right? Will it give the same result?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_status2 (
  `Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `AVG` int(10) unsigned
  )
ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT into tmp_status2 (`Id`, `AVG`) 
SELECT t.`Id`, AVG(se.`value`) as `AVG`
FROM tmp_status t, stuff ss, stuff_history se
WHERE 
   etc...
GROUP BY t.`Id`
ORDER BY t.`Id`;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent. I don't think that creating the table directly will set options like `NOT NULL`, but it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting this into a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` followed by an `INSERT...SELECT` won't help.

In MySQL, when you SELECT from a table in a way that saves the result in some table or variable instead of simply returning the result to the client, the rows you read will be locked with a "shared lock".

Any type of query that does both reads and writes in the same statement is affected:

- `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...;`
- `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...;`
- `SET @myvariable = (SELECT ...);`
- Updating a child row in another table, which references this table with a foreign key.
- Reading a table from a trigger.

The only way to avoid the shared lock is to do a regular `SELECT` query that returns a result set back to the client, then the client may use the result in a subsequent `INSERT` to fill your temporary table. This may be too slow, depending on the number of rows, because it has to copy them to your client and back again.

Another solution is to optimize the query with indexes, so it doesn't take so long. You haven't shown the full query so I don't know what joins and conditions you have. Also I don't know the table structure you currently have. So I can't recommend any specific optimizations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It explains a lot. Given that this is a report generator that runs in the background once a day on a lightly loaded system, speed isn't critical, tho database resources are. I'll have to rewrite the script then, perhaps getting rid of the Temporary in-memory tables and maybe dumping the data to a file and having a go with some 'awk' scripts.